# Lua - How do I change the first line of a .csv file?

Tags: csv, lua

I have a system generated feed.csv file that has generic column headers e.g below...

```
created_at  entry_id    field1  field2  field3  field4  field5  field6  field7  field8
2021-02-03 06:47:02 UTC 2614    18  19.1    18  20  16.7    15.8    6.7 10.00
2021-02-03 07:17:02 UTC 2615    18  19  18  20  16.6    15.7    6.6 10.00
2021-02-03 07:47:02 UTC 2616    18  19  18  20  16.5    15.6    6.5 9.90
```

Using Lua, how can I change that first line to something like this..

```
created_at  entry_id    front_room  bed_1   bed_2   kitchen outside bathroom    shed    porch
```

I have an idea for the start, but not sure at all what to do next ?

```
local tempfile = io.open(mnt/nas/feed.csv, "r") -- the .csv file to read.
local lines = {}
local lineCt = 1
    for line in tempfile:lines() do
        if(lineCt == 1) then 
    ????
```

Answer (score 1):

```lua
local tempfile = io.open(mnt/nas/feed.csv, "r") -- the .csv file to read.

local field_names = { "front_room", "bed_2", "bed_2", "and so on..." }

local function replace_fields(header)
   -- Replace all "fieldXX" strings
   return header:gsub("field%d+", function(field)
      -- Extract the number from the "fieldXX" string
      local num = tonumber(field:match("%d+"))
      -- Look up the correct name and return that
      return field_names[num]
   end)
end

local header = tempfile:read()
-- Filter the header then do something with it
do_something_with(replace_fields(header))
-- Now iterate over the remaining lines and use them unmodified
for line in tempfile:lines() do
   do_something_with(line)
end
```

Using coroutines, you can easily build an iterator that filters the first line and then returns the rest unmodified, if you want to re-use that sort of code a lot.

Comment: Many thanks, however I receive an error - Runtime error: Line 18: attempt to call global 'do_something_with' (a nil value) ?

Comment: @nodecentral Yes, that's where you're supposed to put your own code that does something with the CSV lines

Comment: thanks @DarkWiiPlayer although I’m not sure what to put, I just want to replace that first line of generic column names, with more accurate ones ? What would you do ?

Comment: @nodecentral So you just want to write all the changed files to another file?

Comment: sorry, I’m not sure how to answer that, my goal was just to change the first line/row of the CSV as it’s written to the table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I needed with following code.. (thanks for the help @darkwiiplayer

```
local hFile = io.open("mnt/nas/feed.csv", "r")--Reading.
local field_names = { "conservatory", "kitchen", "hallway", "living_toom", "front_room", "lean_to", "outside", "cabin" }

local function ModifyLine(header)
   -- Replace all "fieldXX" strings
   return header:gsub("field%d+", function(field)
      -- Extract the number from the "fieldXX" string
      local num = tonumber(field:match("%d+"))
      -- Look up the correct name and return that
      return field_names[num]
   end)
end

local lines = {}
local restOfFile
local lineCt = 1
    for line in hFile:lines() do
        if(lineCt == 1) then --Is  the line to modify
            lines[#lines + 1] = ModifyLine(line) --Change old line into new line.
            restOfFile = hFile:read("*a")
        break
      else
        lineCt = lineCt + 1
        lines[#lines + 1] = line
        end
    end
hFile:close()

hFile = io.open("mnt/nas/feed.csv", "w") --write the file.
for i, line in ipairs(lines) do
  hFile:write(line, "\n")
end
hFile:write(restOfFile)
hFile:close()
```